How to enhance/optimize LLM chat tool with streamlit
An interactive chat tool QA-Pilot that leverages Ollama(or openAI) models for rapid understanding and navigation of GitHub code repository or compressed file resources.
It used python + streamlit + chromadb, it's slow when load the page or switch to the different location.
Feel free to share you ideas.
no idea so far, feel free to share

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
